# Use of which.max function to find and store a node value from a list of lists

Tags: r, random-forest

Using the `caret` package in `R`, I am trying to fine-tune and run random forest (RF) regression. I am following [this](https://www.guru99.com/r-random-forest-tutorial.html) tutorial.

During the fine-tuning process, I am running several models (saved in a list) where I am searching which `max.nodes` value gives the model with the highest *R-squared*. Running `str(summary(results_mtry))`:

```
List of 6
 $ values    :'data.frame': 10 obs. of  33 variables:
  ..$ 5~MAE      : num [1:10] 7.19 10.76 5.94 9.8 7.19 ...
  ..$ 5~RMSE     : num [1:10] 9.65 14.01 7.83 12.07 9.3 ...
  ..$ 5~Rsquared : num [1:10] 0.424579 0.009119 0.764428 0.000589 0.47881 ...
  ..$ 6~MAE      : num [1:10] 7.17 10.69 6.08 9.67 7.11 ...
  ..$ 6~RMSE     : num [1:10] 9.62 13.98 7.93 11.95 9.06 ...
  ..$ 6~Rsquared : num [1:10] 0.42625 0.01011 0.76318 0.00568 0.50504 ...
  ..$ 7~MAE      : num [1:10] 7.15 10.68 6.19 9.62 7.11 ...
  ..$ 7~RMSE     : num [1:10] 9.57 13.99 7.96 11.99 9.02 ...
  ..$ 7~Rsquared : num [1:10] 0.43125 0.00794 0.76992 0.00555 0.51089 ...
  ..$ 8~MAE      : num [1:10] 7.12 10.79 6.2 9.56 7.03 ...
  ..$ 8~RMSE     : num [1:10] 9.54 14.07 7.85 11.94 8.84 ...
  ..$ 8~Rsquared : num [1:10] 0.4352 0.0075 0.7752 0.0118 0.5366 ...
  ..$ 9~MAE      : num [1:10] 7.09 10.88 6.21 9.58 6.97 ...
  ..$ 9~RMSE     : num [1:10] 9.46 14.24 7.83 11.92 8.79 ...
  ..$ 9~Rsquared : num [1:10] 0.4435 0.00364 0.77259 0.01597 0.54392 ...
  ..$ 10~MAE     : num [1:10] 7.14 10.96 6.18 9.64 6.86 ...
  ..$ 10~RMSE    : num [1:10] 9.49 14.28 7.82 11.94 8.68 ...
  ..$ 10~Rsquared: num [1:10] 0.44116 0.00333 0.77282 0.01974 0.55635 ...
  ..$ 11~MAE     : num [1:10] 7.11 10.97 6.32 9.67 6.85 ...
  ..$ 11~RMSE    : num [1:10] 9.47 14.33 7.91 12.03 8.67 ...
  ..$ 11~Rsquared: num [1:10] 0.44298 0.00205 0.77089 0.01725 0.56302 ...
  ..$ 12~MAE     : num [1:10] 7.09 11.05 6.21 9.64 6.83 ...
  ..$ 12~RMSE    : num [1:10] 9.4 14.41 7.82 11.99 8.67 ...
  ..$ 12~Rsquared: num [1:10] 0.4508 0.0016 0.7759 0.0206 0.5624 ...
  ..$ 13~MAE     : num [1:10] 7.2 11.08 6.18 9.67 6.79 ...
  ..$ 13~RMSE    : num [1:10] 9.48 14.48 7.72 12.07 8.57 ...
  ..$ 13~Rsquared: num [1:10] 0.441933 0.000875 0.779608 0.016986 0.576059 ...
  ..$ 14~MAE     : num [1:10] 7.18 11.16 6.2 9.7 6.86 ...
  ..$ 14~RMSE    : num [1:10] 9.42 14.65 7.74 12.11 8.61 ...
  ..$ 14~Rsquared: num [1:10] 4.49e-01 6.88e-05 7.73e-01 1.47e-02 5.71e-01 ...
  ..$ 15~MAE     : num [1:10] 7.13 11.3 6.33 9.76 6.88 ...
  ..$ 15~RMSE    : num [1:10] 9.42 14.7 7.78 12.16 8.62 ...
  ..$ 15~Rsquared: num [1:10] 4.48e-01 1.39e-08 7.69e-01 1.59e-02 5.71e-01 ...
 $ call      : language summary.resamples(object = results_mtry)
 $ statistics:List of 3
  ..$ MAE     : num [1:11, 1:7] 5.94 6.08 6.19 6.2 6.21 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "Min." "1st Qu." "Median" "Mean" ...
  ..$ RMSE    : num [1:11, 1:7] 7.83 7.93 7.96 7.85 7.83 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "Min." "1st Qu." "Median" "Mean" ...
  ..$ Rsquared: num [1:11, 1:7] 0.000589 0.005676 0.005555 0.007499 0.003643 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "Min." "1st Qu." "Median" "Mean" ...
 $ models    : chr [1:11] "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
 $ metrics   : chr [1:3] "MAE" "RMSE" "Rsquared"
 $ methods   : Named chr [1:11] "rf" "rf" "rf" "rf" ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:11] "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "summary.resamples"
```

I want to store in a variable the node *value* which has the highest *R-squared*.

In the code below, in the first loop I am searching for the *best* `maxnodes` value (*best* = model with the highest *R-squared*) so I can use this value (i.e., the node value) in the second loop in the parameter `maxnodes =`).

The code:

```
block.data = read.csv("path/block.data.csv")

set.seed(123)

samp <- sample(nrow(block.data), 0.75 * nrow(block.data))

train <- block.data[samp, ]

test <- block.data[-samp, ]

# define the control
trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, search = "grid")

# search best maxnodes
store_maxnode = list()
tuneGrid = expand.grid(.mtry = 1)
for (maxnodes in c(5:15)){
  set.seed(456)
  rf_maxnode = train(ntl ~ ., 
                     data = train, 
                     method = "rf", 
                     metric = "RMSE", 
                     tuneGrid = tuneGrid, 
                     trControl = trControl, 
                     importance = TRUE, 
                     nodesize = 14, 
                     maxnodes = maxnodes, 
                     ntree = 500)
  current_iteration = toString(maxnodes)
  
  store_maxnode[[current_iteration]] = rf_maxnode
}

results_mtry = resamples(store_maxnode)
summary(results_mtry)

# search best ntree
store_maxtrees = list()
for (ntree in seq(from = 500, to = 2000, by = 100)) {
  set.seed(789)
  rf_maxtrees = train(ntl ~ ., 
                      data = train, 
                      method = "rf", 
                      metric = "RMSE", 
                      tuneGrid = tuneGrid, 
                      trControl = trControl, 
                      importance = TRUE, 
                      nodesize = 14, 
                      maxnodes = 10, #### here I want to place the node number from the previous loop #### 
                      ntree = ntree)
  key = toString(ntree)
  store_maxtrees[[key]] = rf_maxtrees
}

results_trees = resamples(store_maxtrees)
summary(results_trees)
```

As suggested in the comments, I need the `which.max` function but I can't type the code properly.

The dataset:

```
block.data = structure(list(ntl = c(59.2700004577637, 116.720001220703, 91.8600006103516, 
50.3199996948242, 130.020004272461, 97.0800018310547, 69.3300018310547, 
49.6699981689453, 46.75, 62.4099998474121, 62.7099990844727, 
51.3499984741211, 44.6500015258789, 34.8499984741211, 39.2200012207031, 
42.439998626709, 45.4700012207031, 38.7900009155273, 40.2000007629395, 
38.8199996948242, 48.2400016784668, 45.7000007629395, 47.810001373291, 
53.1300010681152, 49.560001373291, 43.5900001525879, 44.2000007629395, 
38.9300003051758, 34.8499984741211, 34.4799995422363, 56.3600006103516, 
55, 45.0499992370605, 43.439998626709, 40.9700012207031, 47.0499992370605, 
48.0999984741211, 57.9199981689453, 51.310001373291, 38.5400009155273, 
43.6800003051758, 50.25, 48.8800010681152, 41.2599983215332, 
40.75, 42.9599990844727, 46.6599998474121, 48.3800010681152, 
61.8199996948242, 61.0800018310547, 41.2700004577637, 46.1199989318848, 
22.8799991607666, 47.3699989318848, 43.6300010681152, 38.4300003051758, 
40.8699989318848, 48.7299995422363, 44.4700012207031, 45.4900016784668, 
61.6199989318848, 54.9500007629395, 37.9599990844727, 43.439998626709, 
41.4000015258789, 47.9900016784668, 41.9700012207031, 37.2299995422363, 
42.1800003051758, 49.560001373291, 43.7099990844727, 46.0800018310547, 
54.4000015258789, 52.4599990844727, 44.1699981689453, 48.8199996948242, 
17.2999992370605, 35.7799987792969, 57.0699996948242, 52.4599990844727, 
41.9000015258789, 36.2599983215332, 38.8400001525879, 42.1699981689453, 
42.4599990844727, 39.0099983215332, 38.9799995422363, 38.7599983215332, 
41.9300003051758, 30.3400001525879, 35.4599990844727, 48.6100006103516, 
55.5400009155273, 57.689998626709, 45.6300010681152, 39.0999984741211, 
34.5999984741211, 40.5099983215332, 34.0699996948242, 31.5900001525879, 
28.6100006103516, 24.7299995422363, 29.7299995422363, 32.1300010681152, 
39.5400009155273, 41.7900009155273, 63.9000015258789, 62.810001373291, 
49.3499984741211, 49.9000015258789, 47.4700012207031, 43.689998626709, 
43.1300010681152, 41.3499984741211, 33.560001373291, 26.7000007629395, 
20.1499996185303, 13.960000038147, 18.7399997711182, 42.3899993896484, 
41.6500015258789, 57.4500007629395, 60.3300018310547, 61.9599990844727, 
61.9199981689453, 48.5800018310547, 41.4099998474121, 43.1100006103516, 
45.4500007629395, 52.4500007629395, 58.8699989318848, 44.8400001525879, 
28.1599998474121, 15.5299997329712, 11.5100002288818, 16.3199996948242, 
34.2099990844727, 49.1100006103516, 54.6599998474121, 52.1500015258789, 
52.9300003051758, 58.1500015258789, 52.1100006103516, 43.7299995422363, 
46.8699989318848, 53.2900009155273, 57.310001373291, 64.5400009155273, 
40.9000015258789, 22.5799999237061, 11.5600004196167, 9.77000045776367, 
32.4099998474121, 47.4199981689453, 51.3300018310547, 56.1100006103516, 
50.8800010681152, 44.560001373291, 42.4700012207031, 44.1599998474121, 
48.75, 60.1699981689453, 49.9500007629395, 37.4000015258789, 
36.1699981689453, 53.8800010681152, 58.6599998474121, 61.1500015258789, 
50.3699989318848, 36.1800003051758, 42.8600006103516, 42.7999992370605, 
46.8699989318848, 48.1800003051758, 44.3699989318848, 30.1000003814697, 
52.3699989318848, 63.2599983215332, 62, 52.6699981689453, 41.5299987792969, 
48.4900016784668, 46.9500007629395, 41.7000007629395, 44.2000007629395, 
38.0999984741211, 27.0400009155273, 40.6300010681152, 49.7099990844727, 
49.7099990844727, 39.8800010681152, 43.6599998474121, 46.7000007629395, 
39.2200012207031, 35.0999984741211, 26.2900009155273, 37.9700012207031, 
43.2299995422363, 40.689998626709, 42.5, 43.0299987792969, 38.4300003051758, 
34.3899993896484, 30.6700000762939, 26, 20.8700008392334, 36.9900016784668, 
38.25, 57.6800003051758, 52.8400001525879, 41.1100006103516, 
39.9300003051758, 31.2600002288818, 27.9400005340576, 30.9599990844727, 
32.9799995422363, 22.3099994659424, 35.5099983215332, 38.4700012207031, 
53.5800018310547, 78.1100006103516, 62.4500007629395, 45.8400001525879, 
42.75, 38.4700012207031, 26.7999992370605, 23.5, 23.5900001525879, 
31.7299995422363, 39.8300018310547, 46.439998626709, 64.1500015258789, 
63.1800003051758, 56.3300018310547, 50.4099998474121, 47.5, 45.939998626709, 
30.1100006103516, 27.5200004577637, 33.8899993896484, 40.5999984741211, 
54.2299995422363, 67.9499969482422, 62.1399993896484, 55.5499992370605, 
52.8499984741211, 49.439998626709, 51.3899993896484, 39.0200004577637, 
29.3700008392334, 34.0800018310547, 43.0699996948242, 49.2299995422363, 
59.3499984741211, 59.0499992370605, 63.1599998474121, 60.4900016784668, 
47.5800018310547, 53.2700004577637, 40.9300003051758, 13.0600004196167, 
23.7399997711182, 34.7299995422363, 44.2099990844727, 51.5299987792969, 
58.7799987792969, 61.3300018310547, 51.0099983215332, 54.189998626709, 
50.7700004577637, 44.8600006103516, 29.6700000762939, 19.1100006103516, 
25.5499992370605, 38.75, 50.75, 52.3600006103516, 53.3400001525879, 
52.8600006103516, 54.7599983215332, 51.0800018310547, 46.8800010681152, 
34.25, 17.1900005340576, 20.9599990844727, 23.5599994659424, 
45.4599990844727, 45.2700004577637, 46.8699989318848, 46.560001373291, 
44.5499992370605, 39.7700004577637, 29.5, 11.3299999237061, 21.4899997711182, 
16.9099998474121, 42.0699996948242, 40.6800003051758, 44.9099998474121, 
43.6800003051758, 42.939998626709, 26.5200004577637, 59.4700012207031, 
47.9700012207031, 51.3300018310547, 54.9300003051758, 51.4199981689453, 
29.4699993133545, 8.31999969482422, 69.9599990844727, 79.1100006103516, 
59.5299987792969, 45.4300003051758, 24.3500003814697, 74.4800033569336, 
75.2699966430664, 55.3499984741211, 41.9799995422363, 38.9599990844727, 
54.1100006103516, 51.0800018310547, 40.6800003051758, 33.4199981689453, 
53.4599990844727, 52.5999984741211, 48.9000015258789, 39.75, 
53.3600006103516, 50.8400001525879, 45.3600006103516, 39.0800018310547, 
43.9700012207031, 35.1199989318848, 35.6599998474121, 32.9000015258789, 
30.3600006103516, 12.0900001525879, 22.2399997711182, 38.5999984741211, 
44.8800010681152, 28.7600002288818, 19.3899993896484, 16.0400009155273, 
24.0400009155273, 33.5900001525879, 29.6100006103516, 15.2299995422363, 
19.0200004577637, 16.6700000762939, 12.3999996185303, 17.4099998474121, 
12.7700004577637, 11.539999961853), pop = c(467.730682373047, 
442.584808349609, 386.824768066406, 404.851593017578, 393.846649169922, 
341.867309570312, 331.978668212891, 420.133941650391, 399.355560302734, 
303.836303710938, 308.739990234375, 373.127471923828, 447.762542724609, 
266.3720703125, 333.298156738281, 409.553863525391, 380.941284179688, 
395.985443115234, 393.493804931641, 414.0380859375, 398.675659179688, 
417.473693847656, 455.329650878906, 444.438934326172, 391.074279785156, 
332.950469970703, 273.676300048828, 375.670349121094, 391.606079101562, 
402.8857421875, 441.001770019531, 468.936431884766, 447.103881835938, 
409.662139892578, 355.491485595703, 306.626922607422, 288.12451171875, 
264.401550292969, 275.680816650391, 275.232696533203, 322.314422607422, 
443.952575683594, 406.246276855469, 325.056121826172, 273.865203857422, 
277.731384277344, 282.733306884766, 273.173400878906, 255.424011230469, 
252.928161621094, 270.775115966797, 300.873901367188, 330.387023925781, 
486.562194824219, 417.766937255859, 328.541778564453, 275.667938232422, 
293.250091552734, 310.384307861328, 294.573760986328, 277.082794189453, 
264.684020996094, 277.013519287109, 332.2822265625, 386.991516113281, 
529.134033203125, 404.797668457031, 337.963989257812, 327.352325439453, 
335.318450927734, 357.170532226562, 379.009216308594, 335.018920898438, 
313.892242431641, 316.136169433594, 360.021911621094, 177.771179199219, 
356.384826660156, 475.251892089844, 477.267425537109, 364.647186279297, 
335.457702636719, 331.359771728516, 352.507507324219, 431.358001708984, 
495.757507324219, 389.088348388672, 340.287353515625, 314.916931152344, 
230.861862182617, 358.379241943359, 447.627899169922, 499.188049316406, 
385.820648193359, 331.904357910156, 335.975555419922, 338.039215087891, 
384.359283447266, 493.854125976562, 447.729370117188, 345.277893066406, 
329.822601318359, 321.495574951172, 292.315155029297, 386.298004150391, 
419.256134033203, 460.856658935547, 474.056365966797, 393.099731445312, 
331.051147460938, 322.845062255859, 325.789916992188, 353.692932128906, 
478.168914794922, 491.732391357422, 355.256286621094, 312.570648193359, 
271.149200439453, 254.103805541992, 305.484161376953, 328.351654052734, 
454.282196044922, 466.519104003906, 438.591888427734, 362.569458007812, 
321.702514648438, 311.144805908203, 318.722686767578, 289.113739013672, 
362.393524169922, 530.498779296875, 488.766021728516, 352.353332519531, 
291.703857421875, 196.083953857422, 169.829040527344, 276.586456298828, 
394.136077880859, 447.649536132812, 357.458465576172, 330.671844482422, 
316.614013671875, 308.682250976562, 307.488372802734, 315.810272216797, 
315.00830078125, 446.569549560547, 525.409790039062, 469.031463623047, 
323.507110595703, 206.240097045898, 136.70866394043, 305.205505371094, 
440.419525146484, 416.188415527344, 320.116851806641, 305.065795898438, 
312.146514892578, 306.988250732422, 303.505004882812, 297.240936279297, 
349.085205078125, 503.130523681641, 436.375579833984, 325.817047119141, 
428.442840576172, 374.009552001953, 308.004852294922, 302.125427246094, 
305.510589599609, 303.826202392578, 307.065765380859, 310.789855957031, 
402.336883544922, 512.603881835938, 341.814819335938, 451.526214599609, 
369.636932373047, 312.189910888672, 303.484680175781, 302.448150634766, 
305.6005859375, 310.20556640625, 361.661041259766, 486.923309326172, 
462.197082519531, 335.660766601562, 434.591369628906, 326.722381591797, 
316.817443847656, 310.796447753906, 305.022094726562, 311.223114013672, 
315.769500732422, 392.485260009766, 497.828857421875, 365.072479248047, 
315.761871337891, 306.943206787109, 305.944671630859, 304.676391601562, 
307.842864990234, 322.399810791016, 408.937316894531, 503.714477539062, 
331.908355712891, 340.755310058594, 335.776062011719, 310.720001220703, 
306.018585205078, 303.140838623047, 314.159790039062, 356.463195800781, 
468.256072998047, 481.448883056641, 366.226470947266, 303.771667480469, 
312.950714111328, 367.753631591797, 372.05712890625, 316.509735107422, 
305.842926025391, 308.080749511719, 324.148742675781, 403.967834472656, 
458.983428955078, 315.220581054688, 306.100189208984, 406.476257324219, 
387.388549804688, 363.384002685547, 332.023681640625, 316.36376953125, 
305.164978027344, 305.761657714844, 332.060546875, 430.189819335938, 
437.18359375, 352.428100585938, 439.877349853516, 344.920806884766, 
321.906311035156, 303.888641357422, 305.658386230469, 301.303771972656, 
309.059204101562, 350.502899169922, 457.789031982422, 404.220825195312, 
348.934783935547, 389.165191650391, 319.257232666016, 312.878845214844, 
299.004425048828, 295.020935058594, 299.496704101562, 315.326171875, 
392.207275390625, 466.010864257812, 360.850219726562, 207.557098388672, 
311.1181640625, 364.520080566406, 421.305114746094, 384.428588867188, 
322.168792724609, 298.988342285156, 303.18896484375, 350.786376953125, 
458.250915527344, 443.151519775391, 324.209350585938, 272.503509521484, 
285.845031738281, 320.443328857422, 406.536590576172, 454.334075927734, 
401.587219238281, 322.675140380859, 308.545257568359, 409.520935058594, 
483.659057617188, 375.045562744141, 255.126037597656, 311.212921142578, 
216.756912231445, 368.455963134766, 458.809356689453, 401.597442626953, 
325.810699462891, 427.660095214844, 482.688262939453, 331.141510009766, 
181.774032592773, 213.352233886719, 187.602554321289, 388.55908203125, 
449.115509033203, 357.346282958984, 417.838958740234, 463.803497314453, 
350.715362548828, 316.349731445312, 438.630187988281, 402.3486328125, 
461.848388671875, 451.344573974609, 387.394012451172, 82.5956802368164, 
381.059661865234, 383.909515380859, 463.255798339844, 382.991790771484, 
282.866302490234, 395.704193115234, 436.873657226562, 471.699554443359, 
365.950927734375, 331.590698242188, 413.536224365234, 461.433929443359, 
435.342834472656, 316.814453125, 340.904754638672, 456.206756591797, 
458.000915527344, 360.565734863281, 335.498718261719, 432.590454101562, 
413.760589599609, 327.622589111328, 356.019195556641, 308.775482177734, 
223.692031860352, 330.171447753906, 328.636505126953, 141.314712524414, 
174.631240844727, 267.42529296875, 291.692108154297, 282.262054443359, 
238.984924316406, 171.093856811523, 278.318084716797, 288.979125976562, 
207.751800537109, 171.422134399414, 269.854309082031, 243.924942016602, 
90.4415740966797, 160.288192749023, 192.350738525391, 92.9382019042969
)), row.names = c(NA, 353L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `which.min` function?

Comment: I have tried using this function, but I am getting all sorts of errors, like for example `Error in which.min(results_mtry$metrics)[RMSE] : invalid subscript type 'closure'`, or `which.min(results_mtry$metrics)["RMSE"]` and more....

Comment: You have not shown a structure named `results_mtry`

Comment: It appears from the second image that you have used some sort of summary operation on some unspecified intermediate object. There is no “mean” column in the `results_try` object. A better description of what was actually done might be helpful.

Comment: When typing `summary(results_mtry)` that's what I am getting (pictures in my question). I did not do any intermediate steps. Perhaps the description in my question is misleading, but from the structure of the `results_try` I think you understand by now what I really need, that is the leading number of node with the lowest RMSE value. I will edit my question so I can make it even more clear.

Comment: Sigh. What does `str( summary ( results_try))` return?

Comment: I posted it in the question the `str(summary (results_try))`. So, if I understand correctly, I need from the _values_ node, the lowest RMSE.

Comment: I asked for the results of str(summarry(.)) because the print output to your console suggested to me that there had been an aggregation into a matyrix like object. Perhaps the `print.summary.resamples()`method will have that aggregating approach used by the package authors. I'm now in front of my office Linux machine and should be able to investigate more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you know saving the workspace that may help the problem.

```
save(file = “d:/filename.RData”)

load(file = “d:/filename.RData”)
```

Comment: I am not sure how this might help my problem. I edited my question to make the issue more clear.

Answer (score 0):

None of the items in that structure have the name “RMSE”. The model results appear to be in the “values” node and are groups of three with a leading numeral. You need to specify what you mean by a -*best* model. Then you  can request how to extract the RMSE, MAE, and R.squared vectors.

Update: The criterion you are using for "best" focuses on the console output from the summary method so looking at the functions itself we see that it is the `$statistics` node of that list which provided the column output your wanted.

```
 getAnywhere(print.summary.resamples)
 (res <- summary(results_trees))
 str(res$statistics)
```

```
     $ statistics:List of 3
  ..$ MAE     : num [1:16, 1:7] 6.14 6.13 6.1 6.09 6.1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:16] "500" "600" "700" "800" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "Min." "1st Qu." "Median" "Mean" ...
  ..$ RMSE    : num [1:16, 1:7] 8.26 8.27 8.24 8.23 8.25 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:16] "500" "600" "700" "800" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "Min." "1st Qu." "Median" "Mean" ...
  ..$ Rsquared: num [1:16, 1:7] 0.000267 0.000356 0.000354 0.000459 0.000414 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:16] "500" "600" "700" "800" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "Min." "1st Qu." "Median" "Mean" ...
```

So to get the other results (name, and other rows in the output) of the particular model associated with the lowest "mean RMSE":

```
     500      600      700      800      900     1000     1100     1200     1300     1400     1500     1600 
12.38410 12.37422 12.36724 12.36738 12.37433 12.37668 12.37817 12.37612 12.37603 12.37757 12.37762 12.37682 
    1700     1800     1900     2000 
12.37743 12.37670 12.37660 12.37835 
> which.min( res$statistics$RMSE[ , "Mean"])
700 
  3
```

So "700" is the name of the model with the lowest mean, at least with the particular random seed chosen. That name could be used as an index for the other items in the $statistics node:

```
lapply( res$statistics, function(m) {m["700", ]})
#--------------
$MAE
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.      NA's 
 6.098544  8.076088  8.313876  9.004538 10.422705 11.462069  0.000000 

$RMSE
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.      NA's 
 8.240275 10.108008 10.976645 12.367242 13.379167 19.823219  0.000000 

$Rsquared
        Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max.         NA's 
0.0003535903 0.1523149642 0.3086307402 0.3073345362 0.3845991906 0.6882134119 0.0000000000
```

Or from the `$values` node:

```
 res$values[ paste0("700~", c("MAE","RMSE","Rsquared"))]
#--------------------
     700~MAE  700~RMSE 700~Rsquared
1  10.940382 16.826602 0.2143293766
2  11.462069 19.823219 0.1058897477
3   8.127457 10.378231 0.2850535351
4   6.098544  8.240275 0.6882134119
5  10.465990 13.490135 0.1316434934
6   8.058966  9.996797 0.3983469331
7  10.292852 13.046265 0.0003535903
8   8.402776 11.575060 0.3433559630
9   7.971363 10.068101 0.5739513655
10  8.224977 10.227731 0.3322079452
```

(This replaces an earlier guess based on how the OP attempts to pull results from the resampled results. It’s mostly here now a a placeholder for the comment. )

Comment: I think in your code you are missing a `)`. Still, if I do `results_mtry$metrics[which.min(results_mtry$metrics)[, "RMSE"], ]`, I'm getting this error: `Error in which.min(results_mtry$metrics)[, "RMSE"]: incorrect number of dimensions`. Above, I have pasted the output of `str(results_mtry)` (it says it's a list of 6) as well as the `summary(results_mtry)`. From the metrics (R squared, RMSE Kappa), I am interested in the (lowest mean) RMSE. The `summary(results_mtry)` shows these three metrics.

Comment: None of the items in that structure have the name “RMSE”. The model results appear to be in the “values” node and are groups of three with a leading numeral. You need to specify what you mean by a -_best_ model. Then you  can request how to extract the RMSE, MAE, and R.squared vectors. (Looks like you need a bit of education on basic R list manipulation. )

Comment: That is correct, the "values" node has the model results (R squared, RMSE, MAE) and there is a leading numeral. As I mentioned in my question, I need this leading numeral (you explained it better what I need). By _best_ I mean the numeral (or model) with the lowest RMSE (as appeared in the second image (the red circle) in my question).